# Jquery can't access Ajax-created Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, element

I have an

1. html table (with tbody inside)
2. jquery function1: $.ajax - gets the data    from Database and fills the table with rows of data (each row is tr    with tds)
3. jquery function2:  counts the number of rows of the table 
   ( $('tbody').find('tr').length )

So 2 works  fine, fills the 1 with rows, but 3 doesn't work (though it works with tables, filled "by hand", e.g. not with ajax-filled ones).

Notes: When I console.log($('table')[0]) returns :

```
<table>
<tbody> 
<tr> <td>1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>2</td> </tr>**
</tbody> 
</table>
```

When console.log($('tbody')[0]) returns:

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

(it sees no trs inside!)

I understand it has to do with Ajax dynamic content.

- What shlould I do to make (3) work?
- Why console.log shows trs for "table", but not for "tbody"?
- What should I read to understand it all and not question about it
  here ever?:)

Thank you all in advance!

PS. 
Ajax-call (real):

```
            function load_tours () {

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'get',
                        url: 'load_tours',
                        data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
                        success:function (data) {

                            $('#tours_table').empty();

                            tableCreate(data);

                            }           
                        });

        };

        function tableCreate (data) {

            $.each( data, function (i, item) {

            var tr = $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text(item.id),
                $('<td>').text(item.name),
                $('<td>').text(item.lastName);
             $('#tours_table').append(tr);

            });
        };
```

Rows counter:

```
rowCount = $("#tours_table").find('tr').length;
```

PPS here is the (temporary) real pages:

http://81b29c97.ngrok.io/test2 (HTML)
http://81b29c97.ngrok.io/js/tours_load_filter.js (JS 1) http://81b29c97.ngrok.io/js/sort_paginate.js (JS 2)

Comment: Can you post the Ajax call along with your functions and HTML, please?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm guessing it's due to a race condition, and you're checking for the information before it's returned.  Be sure the Ajax call has completed, and the rows have been populated before you check for them.

Comment: Okay, Chris, but why then console.log($('table')) shows the <tr>s inside the tbody, and console.log($('tbody')) doesn't?

Comment: `var count = $('#tours_table tr').length;alert(count);`Also where you are calling counter code?

Comment: Agree it sounds like a Race Condition, you should do it after you have modified the table within the AJAX request, look into promises so you get a better grasp of how Asynchronous and Parallelism works :)

Comment: When is `$("#tours_table").find('tr').length;` being called? And where from?  You posted the call itself but not where it is in relation to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to count the rows *after* the Ajax call is completed by using `.always()` event.

Also, you should change from `success` to `done` event, since the first is deprecated.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Reference: [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'load_tours',
    data: $('#search-form').serialize()
    }).done(function(){
        $('#tours_table').empty();
        tableCreate(data);
    }).always(function(){
        alert($('#tours_table tr').length);
    });        
});
```